# Liquibase mysql store newline

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, liquibase

I try to insert a row into mysql using liquibase in a spring-boot app. Something similar to this:

```
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/1.9"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/1.9
                      http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-1.9.xsd">
    <changeSet author="laxika" id="20160508-2">
        <insert tableName="news">
            <column name="title" value="Hello world"/>
            <column name="release_date" value="2016-05-09 00:00:00"/>
            <column name="icon" value="update"/>
            <column name="message" value="
                a
                b
                c
                d
            "/>
        </insert>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

For some strange reason liquibase doesn't add newlines to the sql properly so I end up having one long string in the db. How can I force liquibase to insert with newlines?

Here is the schema for the table I'm trying to insert into:

```
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/1.9"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/1.9
                      http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-1.9.xsd">
    <changeSet author="laxika" id="20150922-4">
        <createTable tableName="news">
            <column name="id" type="smallint unsigned" autoIncrement="true">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false" />
            </column>
            <column name="release_date" type="date">
                <constraints nullable="false" />
            </column>
            <column name="title" type="varchar(256)">
                <constraints nullable="false" />
            </column>
            <column name="message" type="varchar(2048)">
                <constraints nullable="false" />
            </column>
            <column name="icon" type="varchar(32)">
                <constraints nullable="false" />
            </column>
        </createTable>
        <modifySql>
            <append value="ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8"/>
        </modifySql>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try usind CDATA in the XML :

```
    <column name="message" value="<![CDATA[
        a
        b
        c
        d
    ]]>"/>
```

Comment: Just to add to this answer - the reason for this behavior is that in XML, whitespace is considered unimportant, except inside of a CDATA block.

Comment: This kinda is not working for me I receive the following error:

liquibase: The value of attribute "value" associated with an element type "column" must not contain the '<' character.

Answer (score 6):

I tried all above answers, eventually I see an answer on the community forum of liquibase which has the answer:

```
<column name="message"><![CDATA[
a
b
c
d
]]></column>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/1.9"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/1.9
                      http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-1.9.xsd">
    <changeSet author="laxika" id="20160508-2">
        <insert tableName="news">
            <column name="title" value="Hello world"/>
            <column name="release_date" value="2016-05-09 00:00:00"/>
            <column name="icon" value="update"/>
            <column name="message" valueComputed="(SELECT '\na\nb\nc\nd\n' from dual)"/>
        </insert>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me:

        `<insert tableName="AUDIT_ATTR">
            <column name="AUDIT_ID" valueNumeric="601"/>
            <column name="KEY" value="FINDINGS_IN_CATEGORY_NCW_TEXT"/>
            <column name="VALUE">
tra1
la2
la3
            </column>
        </insert>`